# Converting elements in a nested list to dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have nested list as follows,

```
 dput( list(structure(c("123.60", " on"))))
```

I am interested in converting the elements in this nested list into a dataframe. 
For example, the output should be as follows.

```
      code      description      
      123.60    not stated as uncontrolled, with neurological manifestations
      123.50    not stated as uncontrolled, with ophthalmic manifestations
      .
      .
      .
      123.52    uncontrolled, with ophthalmic manifestations
```

Need help converting these elements into a dataframe.

Comment: Try using `dput` in order to make your problem reproducible

Comment: @DavidArenburg, thanks David, I did that now.

Comment: @Science11, did you mean to delete the output of `dput` when you edited your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not exactly a *nested* list, but a list of named character vectors.  You can apply `as.data.frame.list` to each element, then use `rbind`. So if `x` is your list, then

```
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(x, as.data.frame.list, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
## below is optional - converts character columns to appropriate type
## but will also convert some columns back to factors again
df[] <- lapply(df, type.convert) 
df
#      code                                                   description codeSystem codeSystemVersion
# 1  123.60  not stated as uncontrolled, with neurological manifestations     XAZ9CM       XAZ9CM-2012
# 2  123.50    not stated as uncontrolled, with ophthalmic manifestations     XAZ9CM       XAZ9CM-2012
# 3  123.61  not stated as uncontrolled, with neurological manifestations     XAZ9CM       XAZ9CM-2012
# 4   123.7                              peripheral circulatory disorders     XAZ9CM       XAZ9CM-2012
# 5  123.40         not stated as uncontrolled, with renal manifestations     XAZ9CM       XAZ9CM-2012
# 6  123.41         not stated as uncontrolled, with renal manifestations     XAZ9CM       XAZ9CM-2012
# 7   123.5                                     ophthalmic manifestations     XAZ9CM       XAZ9CM-2012
# 8  123.53                  uncontrolled, with ophthalmic manifestations     XAZ9CM       XAZ9CM-2012
# 9  123.52                  uncontrolled, with ophthalmic manifestations     XAZ9CM       XAZ9CM-2012
# 10  123.4                                          renal manifestations     XAZ9CM       XAZ9CM-2012
```

**Update :** You can also do

```
data.frame(do.call(rbind, x), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

And other, likely more efficient, possibilities include

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(x, as.list))
```

and

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(lapply(x, as.data.frame.list, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```

and (thanks to Ananda Mahto)

```
library(stringi)
data.frame(stri_list2matrix(x, byrow=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

All of these would still require a type conversion on the first column if you wish for it to be numeric.

Also, the data from this question seems to have disappeared, so here it is, copied from the edit history.

```
 x <- list(structure(c("123.60", " not stated as uncontrolled, with neurological manifestations",                 
     "XAZ9CM", "XAZ9CM-2012"), .Names = c("code", "description", "codeSystem",                                    
     "codeSystemVersion")), structure(c("123.50", " not stated as uncontrolled, with ophthalmic manifestations",  
     "XAZ9CM", "XAZ9CM-2012"), .Names = c("code", "description", "codeSystem",                                    
     "codeSystemVersion")), structure(c("123.61", "not stated as uncontrolled, with neurological manifestations", 
     "XAZ9CM", "XAZ9CM-2012"), .Names = c("code", "description", "codeSystem",                                    
     "codeSystemVersion")), structure(c("123.7", "peripheral circulatory disorders",                              
     "XAZ9CM", "XAZ9CM-2012"), .Names = c("code", "description", "codeSystem",                                    
     "codeSystemVersion")), structure(c("123.40", " not stated as uncontrolled, with renal manifestations",       
     "XAZ9CM", "XAZ9CM-2012"), .Names = c("code", "description", "codeSystem",                                    
     "codeSystemVersion")), structure(c("123.41", " not stated as uncontrolled, with renal manifestations",       
     "XAZ9CM", "XAZ9CM-2012"), .Names = c("code", "description", "codeSystem",                                    
     "codeSystemVersion")), structure(c("123.5", "ophthalmic manifestations",                                     
     "XAZ9CM", "XAZ9CM-2012"), .Names = c("code", "description", "codeSystem",                                    
     "codeSystemVersion")), structure(c("123.53", "uncontrolled, with ophthalmic manifestations",                 
     "XAZ9CM", "XAZ9CM-2012"), .Names = c("code", "description", "codeSystem",                                    
     "codeSystemVersion")), structure(c("123.52", " uncontrolled, with ophthalmic manifestations",                
     "XAZ9CM", "XAZ9CM-2012"), .Names = c("code", "description", "codeSystem",                                    
     "codeSystemVersion")), structure(c("123.4", "renal manifestations",                                          
     "XAZ9CM", "XAZ9CM-2012"), .Names = c("code", "description", "codeSystem",                                    
     "codeSystemVersion")))
```

Comment: @Science11 - good!  I added `type.convert` to make sure numeric columns end up numerics, and not characters

Comment: Never heard of `type.convert` before...

Comment: @DavidArenburg - It's pretty neat.  It attempts conversion on character vectors to their appropriate types.  Actually now that I think about it, it might not be appropriate here because it just converted the strings back to factors again.  Haha

Comment: Yeah thanks, I know how to read documentation :) Where did you find this gem?

Comment: @DavidArenburg - Actually I first saw it in Ananda Mahto's code

Comment: @DavidArenburg, and I found it when reading the help file for `read.table` one day. Richard, +1, but where did this sample data come from? (And why didn't you share it so others can play with the answer too?)

Comment: @AnandaMahto - I never noticed that OP changed it.  Hopefully it's in the edit history

Comment: @AnandaMahto Yes, I wasn't sure whether it is better to run `as.data.frame.list` first or `data.frame` after `do.call(rbind, x)`.  Both are probably expensive on large data

Comment: @AnandaMahto - not sure if you were going to post the `stringi` method.  I added it but if you want to post it I'll remove it